# Cant run Qt python application, "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in "

Tags: python, qt

I have made a UI using Qt designer for a Python application. I have created python code files from the `.ui` files using `pyuic5`. However when I try to run my app I get this error: `

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. 
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

I am new to Qt and I have installed it using Brew, and I am using a Conda enviroment with Python 3.9.1.

EDIT: I just tried downloading qt generated py files from github and when I did not create the `.py` files myself it worked. Still, how should I do instead to generate the `.py` files from my `.ui` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I used the Qt compiler, while using pyside2 inside om my code. When I compiled it using `uic -g python -o <ouput_python_file> <input_ui_file>` everything worked fine.